# Power supply automatically disables before the fan has time to reach the minimum current

Tags: power-supply, power, wiring

I bought a [power supply](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/260/RT-125-spec-40862.pdf), which provides 5, 12 and 24V. The issue is that it has a disable if there is not a minimum current on the output after a certain amount of time. After testing with a resistor, I was able to confirm this as with the resistor, it stays ON, and without the resistor it just continuously reboots.

The issue is that when the [fan](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/120/6200N-276038.pdf) I want to use (which is in the correct range of power 0.75A at 24V) is connected to the power supply instead of the resistor, it also continuously reboots.

What I am guessing (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the fan isn't starting fast enough to draw the 0.75A, and before it is able to consume them, the power supply disables itself (in fact I tried to put the resistance in parallel of the fan, start the system, remove the resistance and it still works).

My question is: What should I do in order to draw enough current for the power supply to stay on without rebooting?

The issue that I currently have with resistors is that mines are currently burning out after 2-3min of usages, so I guess they are not able to consume that power(and I'm not sure they are done for this)

Comment: It isn't clear from the datasheet, but I suspect that supply requires a minimum load of 2 Amps on the 5 volt output for proper operation.  Also, the load regulation is given for 20% - 100% of rated load, implying that the supply may not work correctly with less than 20% load. (Why are you using a 136 Watt power supply to drive an 18 Watt fan?)

Comment: Well, I'm beginning in all this, and I was thinking that if it can do 136Watt, it could do less, so I would not have to buy another one for a next project.

The 5V port is already using the 2 Amp(at least I guess, I've the Raspberry Pi plugged on it)

Comment: The RPi won't use 2A. It COULD use 2A. But silently doing nothing I'd say it's probably not using more than 300mA or some such. There's different kinds of supplies. Many single-voltage supplies can tolerate 0% load, or 5% load as minimum, but ones with many outputs sometimes couple the outputs, so they can be cheaper and then they need some load on the primary output to get the regulation going, whether that's 24V or 12V or 5V, that's known by the manufacturer.

Comment: Now looking at the datasheet, you can see in the table for current output and note 6 that every channel needs some current drain within a range to guarantee regulation. If it can't maintain regulation, it'll shut off for safety. In fact it is possible that the start-up current of your Fan is too high, compared to the resistor, a light-ish resistor could load the 24V lightly enough to not force 12V or 5V out of regulation, while the Fan's start current might push them beyond their safety limit at which the PSU resets.

Comment: So why is it working if I start with resistor + fan? Since the fan consume 0.75A and the maximum is 4A, it seems weird to me

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, the datasheet has the answer:

[image]

There is a range for *each* output and a footnote that indicates the total power allowable. It does not say what happens when you go under or over any particular output range.

My expectation (based on experience) is that the highest current (5V) output is primary and insufficient loading causes shutdown, whereas lower loading causes the other outputs to rise out of spec. It's possible they have OVP, in which case they could shut down as a result.

Comment: Yeah I know, I wrote that I reached those minimum current by putting some resistor(on each channel), and I already wrote there was a minimum current to comply. Not sure to understand how your post help